# Typing an any of an any in TypeScript? Parameter 'tag' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have the following code:

```
 export const getTagsByType = (type: string, rawData: any) => {
if (rawData.keywords?.tags){
    return rawData.keywords?.tags.filter(tag => tag.type === type);
}

return undefined
```

}

rawData is a messy blob of whatever that is sent to us by another team. We cannot change it. However, we know that there may be the key in it `tags` that contains another messy blob of stuff that requires further processing.

How do I get this to build in TypeScript?

I get the following error:

TS7006: Parameter 'tag' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an ad hoc type to `rawData` based on what you know about it so far, and maybe improve it over time.

```js
export const getTagsByType = <Data extends { keywords?: { tags: { type: string }[] } }>(type: string, rawData: Data) => {
  return rawData.keywords?.tags.filter((tag) => tag.type === type);
}
```

Note: the `if` conditional is not needed as the null coalescing operator would evaluate to `undefined` if the condition is not met

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgFQIYaoBCAnjiWMHALxwA8AInjHnKDMMgCapwDecANbASAd2g8A-AC5+cFoVkCYFYLPRQAlsgxwAvgG0Auvv0A+ABQrK6mFp0AaOFDyimLWe7wBKGmf4AsABQcM7YAK5QyM6uXgB0wmISqJJxCqhxAGaaADYcUBZWBL7U-gppqjTUtNbA3gDcwXpAA)